# Does anyone know a good javascript library or a way to visualize predictions based on scores?

Tags: javascript, visualization, data-visualization, google-visualization, graph-visualization

I have a table with many entities being predicted to other types of entities with a given confidence score. 
Ex:

```
Entity1 -> type1; score:3.0
Entity2 -> type4; score:1.0
Entity1 -> type3; score:5.0
Entity3 -> type3; score:2.0
Entity1 -> type1; score:3.0
```

I need to visualize this data. Preferably in a matrix diagram or a mapping diagram. The confidence score is the most important feature. It should determine the positions on the chart. I have been looking at HighCharts and some other javascript visualization libraries, but haven't come across a chart that is very useful. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a look at [d3](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/)? This is a great, very flexible, visualization framework. It may be a bit more low-level than the other alternatives you're looking at, but it does include a number of (almost) ready-to-go "layouts", which are mostly different graph types.

Comment: Actually protovis has some good matrix diagrams.

Comment: d3 is actually the successor of protovis (from the same author); afaik, most (if not all) future work will go into that library.